# Object made from points with image background

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to achieve result like in the image below. Basically, an object having a background image and masked with n points. I guess the best way is to do it with js canvas, and what functions/libraries would be the best to use?

[image]

Comment: You may try SVG. Have a look http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Html5 has a built-in clipping function that you can use for your effect.

1. Define a canvas path.
2. Call `context.clip()`
3. Any new drawings will only appear inside the clipping region defined by the path.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var points=[];
points.push({x:261,y:41});
points.push({x:300,y:122});
points.push({x:288,y:223});
points.push({x:150,y:261});
points.push({x:36,y:139});
points.push({x:55,y:81});

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/jellybeans.jpg";
function start(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  clipBackground(points);
}

function clipBackground(points){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    var p=points[i];
    ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y);
  }
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Background clipped on canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>Original image</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/jellybeans.jpg'>
```